# HTML input field right padding

Tags: html, css

I have an input box that I want to be tight to the value string within.  As such, I have the input field resized on each input event, e.g.:

```html
<input value=1 size=1 oninput='this.size=this.value.length'>
```

This works with the exception that both Chrome and Firefox (shown below respectively) leave additional padding on the right within the input field. Firefox being the worst.

[image: Google-chrome] [image: Firefox]

How can I, thru CSS or inline attribute, get rid of the extra padding on the right WHILE maintaining the auto-expanding expanding feature (vis a vis `this.size = this.value.length`)?

**UPDATE:**  While suggestion below fake-fix the problem, none are proper fixes.  It seems, in this regards, `<input>` box is unredeemable.  As such, I'm just moving on to using `<div contenteditable=true></div>`.  The outline hugs the textContent tightly.  Fortunately, for my use, compatibility with `<form>` or autocomplete features are not necessary.

Comment: try text-align: center;  css style so content will be at middle at any width

Answer (score 2):

**It's not padding on the right side.** Your text in the input is just aligned to the left. If you want to have it in the center of your input you can use `text-align: center;`.

```css
input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input value=1 size=1 oninput='this.size=this.value.length'>
```

Comment: In Chrome, once you have entered ~9 characters the value no longer fits within the input. I'm not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine after inputting 3 characters.

**HTML:**

```
<input style="text-align:center" type="text" value="1" size="1">
```

**JS:**

```
function resize(e){
    len = e.target.value.length;
    if(len > 3){
        e.target.size = len-3;
    }
    else {
        e.target.size = len;
    }
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",resize)
```

Comment: not bad idea. works okay, but trim value for chrome and firefox differ, so not ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

playing with width, the output seems to be very close to what you expected. See snippet below. The answer is not 100% accurate but close. Kindly adjust the code to suit your requirement.

Note:

1. you need a extra span element to get the exact width without extra
   padding - this is because, when assigning a fixed width to calculate the width of the input box, slim values like 1 occupies less width and.
2. ensure the extra span element and the target input box have
   some font size.
3. Plan to set a minimum width for the textbox when
   it's empty or slim values like 1.

Hope this helps.

```
<html>
<style>* {
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 11px;
}</style>
<body>
<span id="d1"></span>
<input type=text value="1" style="width: 12px;" size="1" onkeyup="d1.innerText=this.value;this.style.width = d1.offsetWidth;" id="t" />
</body>
</html>
```